# Comparing SQL tables

Tags: sql-server

I am still new in SQL. I am currently having two tables in SQL server and I would like to not exactly compare but more likely see if the one specific column in table 1 is equal to similar specific column in table 2. I have a certain level of success with it but I would like to see also the ones which don't match from table 1 with table 2 (e.g. it can give back null value). Below you can see an example code which might help to understand better my point:

```
select tb1.models, tb1.year, tb1.series, tb2.model, tb.price
from tb1, tb2
where tb1.year = '2014' and tb1.models = tb2.model
```

and here comes the place which I have tried all kind of combinations like <> and etc. but unfortunately haven't got to a solution. The point is that in table 1 I have certain amount of models and on table 2 I have quite huge list which sometimes is not including the same ones from table 1. Due to which I want to see what is not matching exactly so I can try to check and analyse it.

The above example I've shown is returning only the ones which are equal and I see for example that there are 30 more models in table 1 but they are not in table 2 and don't have visibility which ones exactly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw: Do not use `'2014'`, if this value (and the column `tb1.year`) is numeric (probably `INT`). Rather use `tb1.year=2014`. Implicit casts are expensive and can have various side effects...

This sounds like a plain join:

```
select tb1.models
     , tb1.year
     , tb1.series
     , tb2.model
     , tb.price
from tb1
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.models = tb2.model
where tb1.year = '2014'
```

But your `model*s*` vs. `modell` might point to troubles with not normalized data... If this does not help, please provide sample data and expected output!

### UPDATE

- Use `LEFT JOIN` to find **all** rows from tb1 (rows without a corresponding row in tb2 get NULLs
- USE `RIGHT JOIN` for the opposite
- USE `FULL OUTER JOIN` to enforce all rows of both tables with NULLs on both sides, if there is no corresponding row.

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo! I've double-checked and actually you are right and the solution with Left Join worked. It seems when I was trying to do it with join options, I missed some criteria within the tables :)